# How to make this only run once

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>JavaScript Task 3</h1>

<p>This is my Traffic Light script</p>

<img id="red" src="red/red.jpg" width="768" height="614">
<button type="button" onclick="changered()">Change red</button>

<script>
var list = [
    "./red/red.jpg",
    "./red/redyellow.jpg",
    "./red/green.jpg",
    "./red/yellow.jpg"
];

var index = 0;

function changered() {
    index = index + 1;

    if (index == list.length) {
    index = 0;
    }

    var image = document.getElementById('red');
    image.src=list[index];
}


var timer = setInterval(changered, 2000);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I cannot get it to work because it won't run it once and it has to run it once only.

Comment: And I have no idea what you are saying here

Comment: If you want to call changered() once only, why are you using setInterval? Why don't you simply call  changered()?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the function `changered` to execute once. In that case change

`var timer = setInterval(changered, 2000);`

to

`changered();`

But if you only want the button to change the light, there are no need to call the function at all as you have hard-coded the default value in the HTML. So in that case, remove

`var timer = setInterval(changered, 2000);`

Comment: It is to make the array run all the pictures in the array once like a animtion

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?:

```
var list = [
    "./red/red.jpg",
    "./red/redyellow.jpg",
    "./red/green.jpg",
    "./red/yellow.jpg"
];

var index = 0;

function changered() {
    index = index + 1;

    if (index == list.length) {
        index = 0;
        timer = clearInterval(timer);
    }

    var image = document.getElementById('red');
    image.src=list[index];
}


var timer = setInterval(changered, 2000);
```

Note: I only did the bare minimum to accomplish what (I think) you are asking for, your code can be improved significantly.